# Formatting arrays with multiplication Numpy Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vector, format

I have 3 arrays down below `a` and `b` combine to make `a_and_b`. `a` is multiplied by `a_multiplier` and `b` gets multiplied by `b_multiplier`. How would I be able to modify `a_and_b` after the multiplier has been implemented in it.

Code:

```
import numpy as np 

a_multiplier = 3
b_multiplier = 5

a = np.array([5,32,1,4])
b = np.array([1,5,11,3])
a_and_b = np.array([5,1,32,5,1,11,4,3])
```

Expected Output:

```
[15, 5, 96, 25, 3, 55, 12, 15]
```

Comment: There are duplicated value `5` and `1`, how to treat them?

Answer (score 0):

first learn how to use the multiply:

```
In [187]: a = np.array([5,32,1,4])
In [188]: a*3
Out[188]: array([15, 96,  3, 12])
In [189]: b = np.array([1,5,11,3])
In [190]: b*5
Out[190]: array([ 5, 25, 55, 15])
```

One way to combine the 2 arrays:

```
In [191]: np.stack((a*3, b*5),axis=1)
Out[191]: 
array([[15,  5],
       [96, 25],
       [ 3, 55],
       [12, 15]])
```

which can be easily turned into the desired 1d array:

```
In [192]: np.stack((a*3, b*5),axis=1).ravel()
Out[192]: array([15,  5, 96, 25,  3, 55, 12, 15])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I was looking for something more modular like searching for the contents in `a_and_b` and then getting the indexes and its pattern and then multiplying with `a or b_multiplier`.

Comment: `a_and_b[::2] *= 3` and `a_and_b[1::2] *= 5`